# Laravel belongsToMany pivot with multiple columns

Tags: laravel

I currently have two tables in the DB and a pivot table to join them when I need to do a belongsToMany lookup. The basic example is one DB table is 'teams' and the other is 'members'. I can utilize the belongsToMany method on both the team and members model to pull their relationship with each other. A team can have many members, and a member can belong to many teams.

```
public function teams()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
}

public function members()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Member::class);
}

Pivot: team_member
team_id  |  member_id
---------------------
   1     |      1
   2     |      1
   3     |      2
   1     |      2
```

How can I expand on that pivot table to include a type of member for each team? For example, member1 is a leader on team1. member1 is an assistant on team2. member1 is a generic member on team3... and so on. Can I just add a column to that same pivot table? Would it be the membertype_id? How can I relate that to another model/table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting the value of an extra pivot table column laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566675/getting-the-value-of-an-extra-pivot-table-column-laravel)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is pretty common, and Laravel handles it already. Add extra columns to the pivot table and expand your relationships to use `withPivot()`:

```
public function teams(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class)->withPivot(["teamRole", ...]);
}
```

Then accessing is as simple as:

```
$user = \App\User::with(["teams"])->first();
$team = $user->teams->first();
$teamRole = $team->pivot->teamRole;
```

See the Documentation for more information:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

To answer the second part, which is essentially a "Triple Pivot", that requires extra functionality. See

[Laravel - Pivot table for three models - how to insert related models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651405/laravel-pivot-table-for-three-models-how-to-insert-related-models)

for more information, and an associated Package (by the answerer on that question, not maintained, but good for an example)

https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot

Comment: I was heading in that direction, but couldn't grasp how to relate to another column in the pivot table. Looks like I can do a "team_member_role" pivot table each column having a model. Then I can do something like: $team->members->find($id)->roles()->wherePivot('member_id', $member->id)->get();

Comment: Nice; at a glance that looks like it should work. I've only ever come across non-relation columns on pivots (`price`, for example), but it looks like it's possible to handle another layer of complexity. Cheers!

Comment: Circling back on this. How can I get one collection with the 3 relations so I can list it out? Almost like a roster sheet. For one team, list all members and their role for that team. And to do that with one Eloquent call???

Comment: If you've got another question, it's best to ask another one and reference this if necessary. At a high-level, you'd just use multiple values in the `->with()` clause, such as `->with(["users", "users.role", ...])` etc to get all info in a single eloquent call.